# What is this function button for?

Tags: hotkeys, function-keys

F11 with the propeller icon:

[image: propeller icon]

I think I accidentally pressed it while holding the Fn key. I wonder what it has done..

Comment: I assume it either turns the fan on or off, or it changes the temperature curve for the fan. E.g. making it more quiet or louder. Do you hear any difference when pressing it?

Comment: No I don't. I was afraid it may have completely turned off the fan and my processor melt down in a while..

Comment: Don't worry, no laptop manufactur would allow for that like that. On an old HP laptop of mine there was this key too and it would turn off/on an extra fan for the dedicated GPU in the case.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that toggles between Silent and Turbo mode in some Samsung laptops. Sadly, I couldn't find any reference on a Samsung website.

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/f11-key-fan-icon.682396/

Comment: I am sure that if you look in the manual of your laptop, you will get more information.